# Не собираются статические файлы в контейнер Docker

Tags: python, django, docker

Всем привет!  Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить проблему. У меня есть Django-проект, я создаю его образ, запускаю контейнер, проверяю через браузер, все работает отлично, но нет статики. В корне проекта есть папка static, до создания образа собрала ее командой `python manage.py collectstatic`. В settings.py указаны настройки(см.ниже). Содержимое Dockerfile также ниже указываю.

**Settings.py:**

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
load_dotenv()
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(',')
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'logistic',
    'django_filters',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'stocks_products.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'stocks_products.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv('DB_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS':
                 ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
                  'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
                  'PAGE_SIZE': 5,
                  }
```

**Dockefile:**

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /code

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD gunicorn stocks_products.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: А команду `collectstatic` ты выполняешь в контейнере?

Comment: @MaksimAlekseev вроде да, но может неправильно это делаю. подскажи, как это делается?

Comment: Не заметил, что ты ее до создания образа собрала, если вся статика лежит в папке, то вроде все выглядит нормально. Сложно ответить не видя ошибок, можешь зайти в панель разработчика и там поискать ответы.